# Using residue to compute real fractional integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Compute the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{t-1}{t^5-1}dt$$ The hint is to use residues. I tried taking a look at the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), but I don't know which curve in the complex plane I should be integrating over, and what the complex function should be (it should match $\dfrac{t-1}{t^5-1}$ on the real line?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this function has a removable singularity at $t=1$. Take a large semicircle in the upper half-plane with its diameter $[-R,R]$. Let $f(z)=\dfrac1{z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}$.